# Portforwarding fails

Tags: networking, router, firewall, port-forwarding

I know how to portforward and I did it on at least 5 different routers at different places. But at home, it does NOT work. I can't figure out why.

I tried different routers, even routers that I managed to portforward in other places, nothing works. I did many many tests and I can say for shure that the problem is not the portforwarding configuration, it is not the router, and it is not my computer or any firewall on it.

What could be the problem ? What can I try? My ip-adress.com is not the same as my WAN IP (that I can find in my router page), does it mean something ? I'm looking for the complete lists of things that makes my portforwarding not succeed.

Here is my connection collaboration :

MyPC --> WIFI ROUTER : TP-LINK TL-WR841N --> MODEM : Motorola SBV5121 --> Amplifier 2 Data : GVR-2440C --> OUTSIDE HOME CABLES.

Answer (score 2):

Let me guess: The IP address you see on your routers interface is from 100.64.0.0/10? Welcome to the wounder full world of carrier grade NAT!

If I'm right you are sharing an IPv4 address with several other customers as your provider has run out of IPv4 addresses. No way to do port forwarding under these conditions.

If you need access from the outside hope that your provider also offers IPv6 and use IPv6 for access.

Comment: ... or any other RFC1918 private range. Or he's attempting to forward a port the ISP is filtering. (25, 80, 443 come to mind)

Comment: I forwarded few ports in range 40000-50000 and some more to make tests. Everything fails. Is it possible that my ISP is filtering or blocking my ports?